# Как в golang вывести json из массива/среза?

Tags: json, golang

Как кодировать в json таблицу?
Есть

```
type User struct {
    Id  int
    FIO string  
    Login string  
    Password string  .....      
}
var UsersList = make(map[int] User )
```

Я заполняю UsersList. Нужно перебрать, например, где Id=1,2,3.
Как мне потом вывести json-ом этот список? смотрел Marschal, но не знаю, куда его цеплять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все-таки почитайте подробнее что-то по языку, та же сериализация в JSON где только не описана.

Вот пример сериализации того, что вам нужно:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "encoding/json"
)

type User struct {
    Id int
    FIO string
    Login string
    Password string
}

func main() {
    // Тестовые данные
    userList := make(map[int]User)
    userList[1] = User{Id: 1, FIO: "111", Login: "111", Password: "111"}
    userList[2] = User{Id: 2, FIO: "222", Login: "222", Password: "222"}
    userList[3] = User{Id: 3, FIO: "333", Login: "333", Password: "333"}
    userList[4] = User{Id: 4, FIO: "444", Login: "444", Password: "444"}
    userList[5] = User{Id: 5, FIO: "555", Login: "555", Password: "555"}

    // Идентификаторы пользователей, которых нужно сериализовать.
    idsToEncode := []int{1, 2, 3}

    // Собираем данные для сериализации.
    // (в JSON нельзя использовать целые числа в качестве ключей)
    mapToEncode := make(map[string]User)
    for _, id := range idsToEncode {
        mapToEncode[strconv.Itoa(id)] = userList[id]
    }

    // Сериализуем данные.
    data, err := json.Marshal(mapToEncode)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Выводим полученный JSON.
    fmt.Printf("data: %v\n", string(data))
}
```

**Обновление**. Ну это ж простой цикл с условием, если вам нужно отфильтровать еще как-то по-другому данные, это же основы!

```
    ...

    // Собираем данные для сериализации.
    mapToEncode := make(map[string]User)
    for id, user := range userList {
        if user.FIO == "111" {
            mapToEncode[strconv.Itoa(id)] = user
        }
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо))

Comment: А ещё вопрос. Если немножко по-другому: Есть ещё поле родителя, и нужно отобразить,к примеру, всех у кого ParentId==111 ?

Comment: @TwoRS, ответил.